# Centered image on top of line in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create this layout:

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 line"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><img src="http://placepic.me/profiles/160-160" width="160" height="160" class="img-circle"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 line"></div>
</div>

.line {
width:460px;
height:2px;
background:#CCC;
}

.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y8kcsr31/

I have even out the columns in the row but it still doesn't work.

EDIT: Sorry, I trying to achieve this https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjg2z5wud4yzy4d/Screenshot%202014-11-13%2011.49.49.png?dl=0

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: your sample doesn't even reference bootstrap?

Comment: Also you are explicitly setting the width of a column which will break it, especially as responsive breakpoints.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't very helpful. You should include more description on what you want to achieve and what is actually happening.

Comment: Sorry guys. I added an image into the post.

Comment: This is incorrect use of the grid system among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has a design pattern like this:

[image]

Using the grid system to accomplish this is not the correct way to get the desired result.

Since there is no design pattern precisely like this in Bootstrap, let's find something similar:

`.panel`

Will work. *Learn more: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels*

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/yenade

[image]

**HTML very clean:**

```
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-profile">
  <div class="panel-heading text-center clearfix">
    <h4>Name of Person</h4>
        <img src="http://placepic.me/profiles/50-50" class="img-circle">

    <a href="#">Edit Profile</a>    
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.panel-profile .panel-heading {
    position: relative;
}
.panel-profile .panel-heading  h4 {
    margin: 10px 0 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.panel-profile .panel-heading img {
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;
}
@media (min-width:400px) { 
    .panel-profile .panel-heading a {
        font-size: .75em;
        float: right;
    }
   .panel-profile .panel-heading {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
  .panel-profile .panel-heading img {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        display: inline;
        bottom: -25px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Christina :) Adding a border would be better.

Comment: Hi Christina! I hope you are there however I am using the LESS files from bootstrap. Can I still use your code? 
Hope you will see this comment.

@Christina

EDIT: I am still learning how to use LESS.

Comment: Yes you can. First you should learn vanilla CSS. You would take that this css, put it in a custom-name.less file and import that into your output file (the file that compiles directly). Swap out any thing you want with a mixin or variable.

Comment: Hi @Christina. Do you know where can I learn more about this other than Vanilla CSS. Still really new to LESS.

Comment: I learned LESS last year by reading the docs, getting a good compiler, reading articles about it, and trying things out.

Comment: Thank you ver much @Christina! I used the @import method to do it. However why does my results doesn't look like yours? 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/c3a2m3mg322171y/Screenshot%202014-11-15%2019.37.13.png?dl=0

The default bootstrap panels.less file code is over here
http://jsbin.com/wumaxowesa/1/

Comment: You need to post another question regarding how to use less. The @import method is used in the export less file and then compiled to a css file. You can't add less as CSS, it is compiled first.

Answer (score 2):

Your fiddle is not referencing bootstrap. Have a look now.
[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y8kcsr31/6/)

and

```
.line {
height:2px;
background:#CCC;
}
```

is enough.

EDIT:
You can try something like this : - http://jsfiddle.net/y8kcsr31/10/

Comment: Thanks! Please check the image. I am trying to achieve that.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get that. But there are white space in between the lines and the picture.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a fixed width on `.line` Bootstrap works on percentage widths, so if you take that out they sit side by side.

You can see the updated jsfiddle (referencing Bootstrap too) here - http://jsfiddle.net/Tony_C/y8kcsr31/1/

Comment: Thanks! Please check the image. I am trying to achieve that.